# Uses of @dynamic,readonly,read / write in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Iam new to iPhone Programming,Now i want to know about what is the uses of followig..
@dynamic
assign
readonly
read/write
copy
retain
atomic

Comment: have you tried searching at google and stackoverflow, or reading apple's objc language guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html) [on the topic](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17). It's pretty well written and explained.